# list of file owners in folder on linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder with many files. The files have been created by many different users. I do not know about shell scripting.

I need to get the list of the username (only) of the owners of the files.

I may save the output of ls -l and then parse it using perl python etc...

But how can i do this using shell scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two solutions so far are good, but have their limitations.

This should guarantee you properly and recursively search every file in a directory tree.

```
sudo find /some/dir/ -exec stat -c "%U" {} + | sort | uniq
```

In other words, recursively search for files in `/some/dir`, and execute `stat -c "%U"` (print username) on the files, in as few invocations of `stat` as possible (`-exec <cmd> {} +` syntax), then of course `sort` the list of usernames, and in turn cull them to just the `uniq`ue set of usernames.

To limit the search to just *regular files*, then add the `-type f` clause:

```
sudo find /some/dir/ -type f -exec stat -c "%U" {} + | sort | uniq
                     _______
```

Comment: On Freebsd: `find /some/dir/ -type f -exec stat -f "%Su" {} + | sort | uniq`. OP is looking for *files* only, therefore I added `-type f`.

Comment: @simlev I think in Linux, "files" is the generic name for any such thing in a directory, including directories, which are just special files. If looking for just _regular files_, then yes add `-type f`.

Answer (score 10):

```
stat -c "%U" *| sort -u
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple one is

```
ls -l /some/dir/some/where | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq
```

which gets you a unique and sorted list of owners.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar That was a good read, but only worth worrying over if you have oddly-named files.

Comment: @gmeben : since when are spaces considered odd?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Perhaps it's not odd, but if you allow whitespace in your system's filenames, then there are bigger problems at hand.

Comment: to go through the directory recursively, add the `R` switch to the `ls` command: `ls -lR /some/dir/some/where | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq`.

Comment: To include a more complete list of users that also includes group information, suggest the command in the above answer be changed to `ls -laR /some/dir/some/where | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sort | uniq`.  Thanks, @Abdull, for the `-R` suggestion.

Comment: Or, how about this monstrosity: `ls -laR * 2>/dev/null | grep -E "^[-bcdlps][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ] " | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sort | uniq`.  Any streamlining is welcome...

Comment: People, people -- this is what the `find` command is _meant_ for. Try something like this: `find /some/dir/some/where -execdir stat -c "%U" {} + | sort | uniq`.